# LINQ - SELECT certain columns

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am new to LINQ.  Please see the code below:

```
Public Class Person
    Public Name As String
    Public Address As String
    Public Age As String
End Class

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
            Dim p1 As New Person
            Dim p2 As New Person
            Dim p3 As New Person

            p1.Name = "Ian"
            p1.Age = 32
            p1.Address = "8 street"

            p2.Name = "Fred"
            p2.Age = 62
            p2.Address = "5 road"

            p3.Name = "Bernie"
            p3.Age = 59
            p3.Address = "5 road"

            Dim list As New List(Of Person)
            list.Add(p1)
            list.Add(p2)
            list.Add(p3)

            Dim test As IEnumerable(Of Person) = From p In list
                       Where p.Name = "Ian"
                       Select p.Name, p.Age
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

How would I loop through test as it stands?

I know I could do something like this:

```
Dim test As IEnumerable(Of Person) = From p In list
                       Where p.Name = "Ian"
                       Select p
            Dim List2 As List(Of Person) = test.ToList
```

However, what is the point of the SELECT clause as based on this you can only select full objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your result no longer contains an `Address`, it's no longer a `Person`.

The following *does* work:

```
Dim test = From p In list
           Where p.Name = "Ian"
           Select New With { .Name = p.Name, .Age = p.Age }
```

This creates a new, anonymous type which only contains the information you are interested in. The type of `test` is `IEnumerable(Of SomeAnonymousTypeThatDoesNotHaveAName)`.

---

In general, the purpose of the `Select` clause is to do a *projection*. For example, you could project your persons to strings:

```
Dim namesWithAges As IEnumerable(Of String) = 
    From p In list Select p.Name & " (" & p.Age & ")"
```

or to some completely new object:

```
Dim employees = 
    From p In list
    Select New With { .Name = p.Name, .Supervisor = DetermineSupervisor(p) }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it bad practice to use anonymous types like this? +1.

Comment: No, it's perfectly fine. Just note that you cannot return an anonymous type or pass it to a subroutine, so it's only useful in your current method. The return type does not need to be anonymous, by the way: `Select New SomeClassOfMine(p.Name, p.Age)` is perfectly fine.

Comment: I guess you can return a list of persons from the data access layer and then use anomynous types in the business layer as needed?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can work with anonymous type outside of the function that they're created in.

Here's an example.

Instead of defining your query with the signature of `Dim test As IEnumerable(Of Person)`, do it like this:

```
Dim test = _
    From p In list
    Where p.Name = "Ian"
    Select p.Name, p.Age
```

The compiler will infer the anonymous type.

Now you can then use it in functions like this:

```
Public Function GetDisplayItems(Of T)(items As IEnumerable(Of T), toString As Func(Of T, String)) As String
    Return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, items.Select(toString))
End Function
```

This function has a generic type that the compiler can infer so you can call it with anonymous types. Try this:

```
Dim text = GetDisplayItems(test, Function (t) t.Name & " " & t.Age)

Console.WriteLine(text)
```

The result I get is the text `Ian 32`. Obviously this is a trivial example, but in practice you can do a lot with this approach.